# How to add all the omitted "this" keyword to java source automatically?

Tags: compiler-construction, javacc

This is a general, homework-alike question.
It's about the topic of Compiler.
Maybe can be implemented with tools like JavaCC.
The goal may be useless, but the solving methodology is valuable.

I ask because I feel it's something difficult to implement.

I need some project done which can solve this problem, but suggestions are also welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would approach the problem:

- Write a lexer and parser for Java.  The parser should output an abstract syntax tree. Of course for this step a parser construction tool (compiler compiler) is very useful: JavaCC, JJTree, ANTLR, and DMS are some. Luckily there are lots of free grammars I could use or start with.
- Write a second pass that creates a symbol table.
- Write a third pass that walks the tree outputting Java. This pass will have to consult the symbol table to determine which instances of identifiers refer to fields.

Some tools (like DMS) will help with the second and third passes.

Note that for Java, the problem can not be solved in one pass. Consider

```
class A {
    class B {
        void m() { a = b ; }
        int b ;
    }
    int a ;
}
```

Comment: Well, I found antlr4 a good solution. I prefer ANTLR over javaCC because its grammar is reasonable ,so easy to understand and write. though I found openjdk javac source uses code like javaCC(visitor, accept()).  And I havn't tried DMS yet.  Here is my pet project trying to convert java to c source.  https://github.com/neoedmund/j2c